# Rails & YouTube webhooks: PubSubHubbub not POSTing to my callback url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, webhooks

I'm want my app to be notified whenever a specific channel uploads a new video. Best guide I could find was [YouTube's push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). Following their instructions, I setup a rails controller to handle the webhook and setup a subscription for the channel. [Here](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscription-details?hub.callback=http%3A%2F%2F9f9c3a0e.ngrok.io%2Fyoutube%2Fnew&hub.topic=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fxml%2Ffeeds%2Fvideos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3DUCzIcxWbV03Jazr1sAhLxghA&hub.secret=) is confirmation the subscription has been setup.

But no post is being sent when a new video is uploaded. Where's my mistake?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux. I'm trying it out.. Using this as my feed url: https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCzIcxWbV03Jazr1sAhLxghA  but doesn't seem to be working. Is that the wrong format or something?

Comment: It's hard to know if I don't have more data. Feel free to connect with us by email and send us your login name so we can look things up!

Comment: @JacksonCunningham were you able to resolve that? Also, could you share the handler of the atom feed for parsing the POST request? Thanks!